# How to set wpf grid rowspan programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

How to set  wpf grid rowspan programmatically? I am using mvvm pattern.
I have grid lines enabled and the below doesn't work:

```
RowDefinition row0 = new RowDefinition();
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row0)

for (int i = 1; i <= RowsCount; i++)
{
    RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
    myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
    TextBlock txt3 = new TextBlock();
    txt3.Text = i.ToString();
    txt3.FontSize = 12;
    txt3.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    Grid.SetRow(txt3, i);

    myGrid.Children.Add(txt3);
}

ColumnDefinition column0 = new ColumnDefinition();
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column0);


char c = 'A';
for (int i = 1; i <= ColumnsCount; i++)
{
    ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
    myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);                
    TextBlock txt3 = new TextBlock();
    txt3.Text = c.ToString();
    txt3.FontSize = 12;
    txt3.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    Grid.SetColumn(txt3, i);
    myGrid.Children.Add(txt3);

    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            for (int j = 1; j <= RowsCount; j++)
            {
                TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
                txt.Text = ColumnAROI[j-1].ToString();
                Grid.SetRow(txt, j);
                Grid.SetColumn(txt, i);
                Grid.SetRowSpan(txt, 2);
               // Grid.SetRowSpan(txt, TubeRowSpan[j]);
                myGrid.Children.Add(txt);
            }

            break;
    }

    c++;
}

    for (int j = 1; j <= RowsCount; j++)
        {
            TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
            txt.Text = ColumnAROI[j-1].ToString();
            Grid.SetRow(txt, j);
            Grid.SetColumn(txt, i);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(txt, TubeRowSpan[j]);
            myGrid.Children.Add(txt);
        }
```

TubeRowSpan is an ObservableCollection of type int and defined as below. It contains all 1's except at position 2 (3rd element).

```
private ObservableCollection<int> _TubeRowSpan = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    public ObservableCollection<int> TubeRowSpan
    {
        get { return _TubeRowSpan; }
        set
        {
            if (_TubeRowSpan != value)
            {
                _TubeRowSpan = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => TubeRowSpan);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it is working fine

Comment: It might be possible that 4th element overriding the third and wont show 3rd element in 4th row

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't look like MVVM.

Comment: @MarkFeldman I am using MVVM pattern. I am creating grid and setting properties in ViewModel constructor. Above code is in my ViewModel.

Comment: @ethicallogics How to fix it? I don't care about the fourth element. I want to combine the two and display the same string.

Comment: @ser2951819 Please correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like you're calling members of the Grid control from your view model. That's not MVVM, in MVVM the view model should have absolutely no knowledge of the Grid control whatsoever. In MVVM you create data structures in your view model and then the XAML in your View layer binds to those structures via the mechanism of data binding i.e. <MyControl Grid.Row="{Binding RowNum}" Grid.Column="{Binding ColumnNum}" Grid.RowSpan="{Binding NumRows}" etc where ColumnNum, RowSpan and NumRows are all properties that you've created in your view model.

Comment: Also in MVVM you never, _ever_ create GUI elements in the view model (i.e. "TextBlock txt = new TextBlock()"). The view model creates an instance of a child view model class and the XAML again uses data binding to create a TextBlock in response to that and bind to it. I'm sorry to be "that guy" who doesn't actually answer your question but it's important to make sure we're very clear about what you're trying to do. You're not using WPF the way it was designed to be used, if you're ok with that then that's fine, just understand that both your question and any answers you get won't be MVVM.

Comment: @MarkFeldman I am fine if answers are not in MVVM. BTW Thanks for pointing it out to me. But, I want to fix rowspan.

Comment: Have you added RowDefinitions to the Grid control?

Comment: @MarkFeldman yes I have. Again through code. And I can see them populated with textblocks in output window.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to post the rest of your code, notably how you're creating your row definitions. The following code creates 3 rows for each element and sets the rowspan to 2, it's easy to see from the result that it's working as expected:

```
int numChildren = 10;
        int numRows = numChildren * 3;
        for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++)
            this.myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(30) });
        for (int j = 0; j < numChildren; j++)
        {
            TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
            txt.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
            txt.Text = "Row " + Convert.ToString(j);
            Grid.SetRow(txt, j*3);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(txt, 2);
            myGrid.Children.Add(txt);
        }
```

I suspect there's something wrong with your RowDefinitions which is causing them to collapse to a height of 0 making it *look* like it's not working when in fact it is. Try replacing your entire code with mine and then replace your own parts back in bit by bit.

Comment: Why are you multiplying numChildren by 3? Can that be fixed by defining height? Anyways, now I have included my rowdefinitions in question.

Comment: I'm multiplying numChildren by 3 so that I give each child two rows (note I've also given them a colored background) and I separate them by a third row. Sorry if that was confusing, it was just to make it visually easier to confirm that RowSpan was working correctly.

Comment: Oh I see but I can do that coz in my actual code, rowspan can span anthing between 1 and 6.  BTW now I have finished editing my question.

Comment: The first thing that springs to mind is that you're indexing your rows from 1. Grid RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions and zero-indexed.

Comment: No, I hadnt included the 0th row in the question. Now edited the question to include 0th row.